# codificación utf8

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

tengo un problema con la codificación utf8. Estoy usando jqgrid para ver datos en tablas pero las cadenas que tienen tildes y eñes se guardan mal en mi base de datos ya que por ejemplo la palabra maletín se guarda como MaletÃ­n y esto me acarrea muchos problemas a la hora de comparar cadenas y tal. Hay alguna solución para poder codificar esos caracteres y se guarden correctamente en la BBDD?
La pagina está en utf8 que lo he comprobado y los campos de la tabla donde se guardan esas cadenas están en utf8_unicode_ci, el sistema que uso es el motor smarty y el php5.3 sé que es bastante antiguo pero no puedo hacer de nuevo el sistema, alguna idea??
gracias de antemano